# Adding multiple dropdown on clicking a link

Tags: asp.net-mvc, dropdown

I have a link which says "add another field". On clicking the link a dropdown should appear on top with let's say 5 custom fields as list in dropdown. Once user selects a field in that dropdown and clicks hyperlink another dropdown should appear below existing dropdown and with only 4 remaining fields as one is already selected.so how to start this?

https://tutorialslink.com/Articles/How-to-add-control-dynamically-in-Aspnet-MVC-using-Javascript/64 . I have tried to use this link which adds text boxes to get started.

I don't have any code expect for the code in above link which is for text box though. Just need an idea of how to do it in asp.net MvC as i cannot move forward now.

Expected results  is to do the above requirement,  don't have any actual results as of now

Comment: This is very unclear. What do you expect as an answer?

Comment: sorry, if i am not clear.is there any particular thing which i have to explain more? with combination of asp.net mvc , action methods , views and probably jquery/Javascript. I need to achieve above